# Better way to create dictionary of functions

Tags: function, dictionary, julia, anonymous-function

```
#attempt 1: works
f(x::Int64) = x +1
my_functions = Dict("f" => f)

#attempt 2: does not work, something is wrong
new_functions = Dict("g" => g(x::Int64) = x + 5)
```

I'm a novice and new to Julia. Is there a way to accomplish this similar to my 2nd attempt above? Thanks

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński, your solution, link, and warnings about the dictionary type were helpful; I learned alot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use anonymous function syntax like this:

```
new_functions = Dict("g" => x::Int64 -> x + 5)
```

You can read the details how they are used in the Julia manual: https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/functions/#man-anonymous-functions-1.

Edit: notice that if you initially add only one function to the dictionary its type will be too restrictive, like: `Dict{String,getfield(Main, Symbol("##3#4"))}`, e.g.:

```
julia> new_functions = Dict("g" => x::Int64 -> x + 5)
Dict{String,getfield(Main, Symbol("##15#16"))} with 1 entry:
  "g" => ##15#16()
```

So you probably should specify the type explicitly like:

```
julia> new_functions = Dict{String, Function}("g" => x::Int64 -> x + 5)
Dict{String,Function} with 1 entry:
  "g" => ##23#24()
```

or add at least two entries to the dictionary initially:

```
julia> new_functions = Dict("g" => x::Int64 -> x + 5, "h" => x -> x+1)
Dict{String,Function} with 2 entries:
  "g" => ##11#13()
  "h" => ##12#14()
```

Answer (score 3):

For completeness: there's also the possibility to use the normal multi-line function syntax as an expression, which will create a function object with a name (like a "named function expression" in JavaScript; this is handy if you need recursion):

```
julia> Dict("g" => function g(x::Int); x + 5; end)
Dict{String,typeof(g)} with 1 entry:
  "g" => g
```

The first `;` in the line is necessary here. @Bogumił's caveats about typing the `Dict` apply as well, as you can see.

Using the short-form syntax is possible, too, but you have to put the expression into parentheses:

```
Dict("g" => (g(x::Int) = x + 5))
```

Comment: For even more completeness, you can use short-form function definition too. Just remember to put in parens:  `Dict("g" => (g(x::Int) = x + 5))`.